# ImageButton not updating update panel

Tags: asp.net, .net, updatepanel, imagebutton, autopostback

The ImageButton works, but it doesn't update the update panel, hence showing no changes at all.

This is my Update Panel code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPConfig" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate >

  STUFF

  <asp:ImageButton ID="ModT" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/config.png" width="25px" height="25px"/>

  STUFF

 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ModT" EventName="Click"/>
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I can't seem to add the AutoPostBack="true" property either. Can this be done this way?

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ModT" EventName="Click" />
```

I'm pretty sure you've got to tie in your trigger to an event, in this case you're clicking on the object, so tie it into the click event, like above.  Everything else looks ok, let us know otherwise.

Comment: Did it, not working yet, I think the issue comes down to the ImageButton not having the AutoPostback property, but it doesn't let me set it on the ImageButton, it does however on other elements such as DropDownLists.

Comment: I'm going off a fully working async example that I wrote a while back, the other property I have set is ChildrenAsTriggers to false: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx  I'm not using non-default postback anywhere.  And... I think postback gets set to auto when runat="server" is in there, don't quote me on that outside of ajax though :)

Comment: I tried and worked fine,thanks. and some things:
1-I just use <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ModT"/>
2-at first time i use it ,not worked and after google it, i discover my mistake and i've an error because i forgot to use my control (such as grid view or ... )inside the update panel.
now @user1676874 , you can refer here and review your code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105794/imagebutton-does-not-fire-in-updatepanel